# What causes an edit to deviate from the original intent of the post?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

After seeing that [this edit suggestion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31010) got rejected because it "deviates from the original intent of the post", I realized that I have no idea why or how an edit could change the sense a post makes.

What causes edits to do so on PPCG?

Comment: In this particular instance, the edit, while drastic, I don't feel changed the intent of the post. It cleaned up the text and clarified a few things. However, I'm *guessing* at that, since the post itself and the comments underneath it were a right mess, with the OP providing contradictions. From that perspective, I agree with Alex and EMBLEM, that this edit should be rejected since we're not sure *exactly* what the original intent was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What Timmy said in his comment is exactly right:

> this edit should be rejected since we're not sure *exactly* what the original intent was.

I can't speak for the other user who voted to reject the edit, but that's why I rejected it. This was a fairly drastic change to the post (including the voice in which the task is described) and since the post wasn't entirely clear in its intent, it wouldn't be appropriate to modify it in this way; it should be the job of the challenge author to clarify their own intent, particularly when the information they're providing in comments contradicts what's currently in the post.

In general, edits to questions are appropriate if they clarify wording without making assumptions about the OP's intent or if they greatly enhance readability through formatting improvements.